# disable download if no image is present

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, hyperlink, download

The HTML part is given below

```
<a download="<?php echo $value['product_name']; ?>" href="Image/<?php echo $value['product_image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $value['product_name']; ?>" style = "cursor: not-allowed" class="download" disabled="disabled"> Download</a>
```

How do I stop the user from downloading the image if there is no image present in the database?

Comment: <a download="<?php echo $value['product_name']; ?>" href="Image/<?php echo $value['product_image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $value['product_name']; ?>" style = "cursor: not-allowed" class="download" disabled="disabled"> Download</a></td>

Comment: Check for `$value['product_image']` value. The question is vague as `product_image` could not be empty, but the image doesn't exist on server.

Comment: what's the relation to javascript and ajax? there's no code to support the question. Unless this suggest you asking how to do this with those. If so, you shouldn't rely on those but a serverside method. JS can always be disabled by the user.

Comment: Plus, seeing this is db-related, it'd be easier to use a serverside method along with a ternary operator. You can probably use `file_exists()`, but the question is rather unclear, IMHO. Anyway, someone gave you answer below, try that. If it does not solve this question, then post a comment under the answer, or accept it if it did. I have given you comments and someone else but no response; good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In an `if` statement:

```
<?php if ($value['product_image']){?>

<a download="<?php echo $value['product_name']; ?>" href="Image/<?php echo $value['product_image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $value['product_name']; ?>" style = "cursor: not-allowed" class="download" disabled="disabled"> Download</a>

{?php } ?>
```